# MySQL query for returning dates on a monthly basis

Tags: mysql, time-series

I have a problem with building sql query for returning dates on a monthly basis.
The sample table contains dates:

```
    some_date
    ...
    2019-12-19      
    2019-12-20 
    2019-12-23 
    2019-12-24 
    2019-12-27 
    2019-12-30 
    2019-12-31 
    2020-01-02 
    2020-01-03 
    2020-01-07 
    2020-01-08 
    2020-01-09 
    2020-01-10 
    2020-01-13 
    2020-01-14 
    2020-01-15 
    2020-01-16 
    2020-01-17 
    2020-01-20 
    2020-01-21 
    2020-01-22 
    2020-01-23 
    2020-01-24 
    2020-01-27 
    2020-01-28 
    2020-01-29 
    2020-01-30 
    2020-01-31 
    2020-02-03 
    2020-02-04 
    2020-02-05 
    2020-02-06 
    2020-02-07 
    2020-02-10 
    2020-02-11 
    2020-02-12 
    2020-02-13 
    2020-02-14 
    2020-02-17 
    2020-02-18 
    2020-02-19 
    2020-02-20 
    2020-02-21 
    2020-02-24 
    2020-02-25 
    2020-02-26 
    2020-02-27 
    2020-02-28 
    2020-03-02 
    2020-03-03 
    2020-03-04 
    2020-03-05 
    2020-03-06 
    2020-03-09 
    2020-03-10 
    2020-03-11 
    2020-03-12 
    2020-03-13 
    2020-03-16 
    2020-03-17 
    2020-03-18 
    2020-03-19 
    2020-03-20 
    2020-03-23 
    2020-03-24 
    2020-03-25 
    2020-03-26 
    2020-03-27 
    2020-03-30 
    2020-03-31 
    2020-04-01 
    2020-04-02 
    2020-04-03 
    2020-04-06 
    2020-04-07 
    2020-04-08 
    2020-04-09
    2020-04-10
    2020-04-11
    2020-04-14
```

I am currently using query:

```
SELECT some_date FROM some_db
WHERE some_date IN (SELECT max(some_date) FROM some_qts WHERE DAY(some_date) <= DAY(('2020-04-09') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY year(some_date), month(some_date))
```

and i heve returns like this:

```
2020-01-03
2020-02-06
2020-03-06
2020-04-06
```

The problem is when i would like to select days <= 2020-04-02 - then output will skip the months in which the start date is greater than 02 - e.g. the first date of February 2020 is 2020-02-03 - what I would like to achieve is return in that case maximum available date for that point - in my case will be 2020-01-31.

I will be grateful for the hint and guiding to the right solution.

Comment: What start date? Your query as written and with a select days <= 2020-04-02  is only ever going to return the second of every month and whats more will project forward in time. Is there something missing from this question?

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to return the second each month or when there is no second of corresponding month then the nearest preceding day (in above example will be 2020-01-31 for February)

Comment: To clarify a little please.  Are you really looking for the LAST Day of the month in which data exists for a given month?  So, for later querying purposes, you are trying to get all data From Jan 1 - 31, Feb - 28 (or 29), March 1 - 31, etc?

Comment: I apologize for the difficulties in understanding but it probably results from not good language skills.
Im looking for LAST DAY of each month WHICH IS SMALLER THAN ... (for example second day on month) - but - if corresponding month do not have record smaller than ... (for example second day on month) then return nearest preceding day (because in above example February do not have second or first day record so in that case for February should be nearest preceding day: 2020-01-31)